# How to return a house number value based on a given house number and postal code

Tags: r, regex

Please look at the text example below

```
Company X
                                               Fakestreet 97,
This an invoice. Please pay :)                 3000 AB Fakecity
```

I am working on a regex pattern (in R) which returns a string of text from a **matching house number** (97) to match of a given **postal code (3000 AB) matches**.
In practice, there are always spaces, (line)breaks and other characters between the postal code and house number.

My current pattern for this match is:

```
\\b(97){1}\\b((.|\r\n|\r|\n|))*(3000 AB)
```

I only want to return the text from the match with '**97**' number from 'fakestreet' until the match with the postal code. But **only if a given postal matches as well** (3000 AB). In

What does my pattern has to look like? My current pattern is giving me problems:

It 'goes on' endlessly and won't stop. This probably is because of the `((.|\r\n|\r|\n|))+` pattern.

My current pattern for this match is:

```
\\b(97){1}\\b((.|\r\n|\r|\n|))*(3000 AB)
```

A breakdown of the 'logic'

find and match the postal code

- (3000 AB)

Find a specific matching house number (and no other number), single match and surrounded by word boundaries

- `\\b(97){1}\\b`

'bridge' the spaces between the postal code and the house number found. Right now this returns all characters matched.

- `((.|\r\n|\r|\n|))*`

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Doing something like this with regular expressions will be quite complex, if not impossible, due to the fact that you’re trying to perform a match on only part of the document, and the rest of the document might contain arbitrary interspersed text. Ideally you’d first extract just the target text (here, the address) from the rest of the text. However, I’m unaware of any library that does this on text. It’s usually done on image data prior to OCR.

Comment: @KonradRudolph good point. I use two steps now. First i extract the text between the two matches. So everything between 97 (house number) and 3000 AB (postal code). Then in step 2 I extract the 97 from it. This works fine. I only run in to trouble with the first step. Do you have any suggestions to extract just the text from house number match to postal code match?

Comment: I edit the question to 'extracting a string of text from housenumber to postal code only. Makes thing more simple and still helps me (if solved).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Can you give me some pointers about how to tackle this problem pre-OCR? Right now I try to find this stuff after I read the image/pdf/word-document.

Comment: I’m afraid I can’t help there, I’ve never actually done this myself. I can only give you the relevant term to help you search for resources, it’s [document layout analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_layout_analysis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your adjusted question the following should work, but I’m not sure whether the result is useful:

```regex
\b97\b.*?3000 AB
```

The key to making this work is to enforce `.` to match newlines as well. With the stringr package, this can be done by specifying `dotall = TRUE`:

```
str_match(text, regex('\\b97\\b.*?3000 AB', dotall = TRUE))
#      [,1]
# [1,] "97,\nThis an invoice. Please pay :)                 3000 AB"
```

Note that this is using a *nongreedy quantifier*, `*?` to match *as little as possible* between the house number and the post code.

In base R this even works without additional flags:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\b97\\b.*?3000 AB', x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "97,\nThis an invoice. Please pay :)                 3000 AB"
```

Comment: This worked very nicely. And much more efficiënt as well. Thank you!